# How to prevent submit, do an ajax request, then finish submit?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have the following scenario

1. User fills out form and hits submit
2. I want to perform an ajax request to resolve a value for one of the form fields
3. Once I have resolved the ajax request I wish to populate a hidden form field and then submit the form.

Can this be done with jquery?

```
$form.on('submit', function () {
  // at this point I can begin the ajax request but there will not be enough time
  // for the ajax request to complete, the ajax request will also require a callback
});
```

Is there a know pattern for handling this situation?

EDIT:

I just want to clarify what my problem was here. I couldn't figure out how to do the ajax request inside the submit event handler as ajax requests are asynchronous and the form would simply submit anyway. $.ajax provides an 'async:flase' option which is what I needed and solved my problem.

Thanks

Comment: please share your code what have you tried so far.

Comment: yes. You can do this with jquery.

Comment: Three minus votes, wow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to use the `success` attribute of a JQuery ajax call.

If the data check does not pass you will want to `return false;` to cancel the form submit.

```
$form.on('submit', function () {
    $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: 'firsturltarget',
            data: formData,
            success: function (dataCheck) {
            if (dataCheck == 'value') {
                // Data Check passed finish submitting form
                $.ajax({
                     type: "POST",
                     url: '/login/spam',
                     data: formData
                 });
            }
            else {
                return false;  // Data Check invalid, cancel submit
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: this is basically it but the bit that everyone seems to have missed is that the async: false property will required. ajax requests are asynchronous by default. Thanks

Comment: You wouldn't need `async:false` in this case because `success` waits for the response of the ajax call.

Answer (score 1):

use

```
$( "#target" ).submit(function( event ) {
  alert( "Handler for .submit() called." );
  event.preventDefault();
});
```

on form

and to submit it use

```
$( "#other" ).click(function() {
  $( "#target" ).submit();
});
```

Comment: are you suggesting I use two forms

Comment: #target is your form #other is your button which you want to click to fetch the response after submitting form

Answer (score 1):

firstly write bind an submit event.

```
$("#form-id").submit(function(){
              //check the input here
            $.ajax({
                    url:"something",
                    type:"post",
                    data:{label:value},
                    success:function(data){
                     //populate values in hidden field
                     return true;
                    },
                    error:function(){
                    }
                });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The best way as far I know to submit a form with jquery is

```
$('body').on('submit', '#FormId', function(event){

    event.preventDefault(); //stops execution of default form action
    $.ajax({
        url : 'localhost/project/controller/method', //type your form submit method path
        type : 'post', //your form method...either get or post
        data : $(this).serialize(), //by this all input field data will be grabbed
        dataType : 'json', //the data type that you want back from your form submit method
        success: function(data)
        {
           //your code after successful submission of your form
        }  
    });

});
```